# generic in autowired in spring 5

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection, autowired

in spring 5 ,I want to use Generic in Autowired.
for example thought I have utill Class and in the class have method that convert StudentDTO to StudentEntity and vice versa.

```
@Component
public class Convert<T,U> {

    public <T,U> U convertEntityAndDTO(T t, U u){
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(t,u);
        return u;
    }
}
```

now I want to inject it in the SudentService class and use them

```
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    Convert convert;

//I need both of them in class
//convert<Student,StudentDTO> convert
//convert<StudentDTO,Student> convert

    public StudentDTO getStudent(Integer id){

        Student student = studentRepository.getStudent(id);
        Object o = convert.convertEntityAndDTo(student, new StudentDTO());

        return (StudentDTO)o;
    }
```

i can use downcast but can't use generic

```
 convertEntityAndDTo(student, new StudentDTO());
```

```
 convertEntityAndDTo(studentDTO, new Student());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for two instances of a completely genericised class right?

First thing you need two instances of your bean so `@Component` won't work as that creates a single instance. Instead you need a `@Configuration` annotated class in which you can define two `@Bean` annotated methods returning the appropriately genericised types.

Now due to type erasure you can't just declare two properties of the expected genericised type and `@Autowired`annotation as autowiring is by type and so at runtime both beans are the same type. Instead you can autowire by name - say one bean is defined in a method called `fromDtoConverter()` and the other in a method called `toDtoConverter()` then instead of `@Autowired` use `@Resource("fromDtoConverter")` and `@Resource("toDtoConverter")` on your genericised properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring 4 you can do auto wiring of generics. The problem is that you are not telling your service which `Convert` type to inject. Try to add the type on the @Autowire in your service:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    Convert<Student, StudentDTO> convert;

    public StudentDTO getStudent(Integer id) {

        Student student = studentRepository.getStudent(id);
        Object o = convert.convertEntityAndDTo(student, new StudentDTO());

        return (StudentDTO) o;
    }
}
```